# Unexpected Regular Expression Output With Javascript's Replace Function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am creating a javascript function that retrieves an `xxd` (bash) output and splits it into 3 pieces. The left piece (with offsets) called offsets, a middle piece called rawVals and the right piece called sidebar.

I have tested the regular on plenty of other `xxd` outputs and they all work. However, when the following output is given, the regular expression seems to add unexpected characters:

Output (some offsets flipped for explaining purpose):

```
00054280: c003 000a b042 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  .....B..........
00054290: 0000 0000 cf11 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  ................
00054260: 8502 a861 2000 0000 3c40 8c49 fd5d 8646  ...a ...<@.I.].F
00054270: 3c40 8c49 ac00 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000  <@.I............
```

Normal behaviour results in:

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00054280: | c003 000a b042 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000 | .....B.......... |
| 00054290: | 0000 0000 cf11 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000 | ................ |

Unexpected behaviour results in:

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00054260:**].F** | 8502 a861 2000 0000 3c40 8c49 fd5d 8646 **].F** | ...a ...<@.I.].F |
| 00054270:**...** | 03c40 8c49 ac00 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000 **...** | <@.I............ |

For some reason `].F` & `...` are added after the offset and rawVals content.

Javascript code:

```
  function getSplitXxdOutput(content){
    var splitRegex = /([a-fA-F0-9]*:)(?: )((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4} ){8})(?: )(.{16})/g
    var offsets = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$1');
    var rawVals = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$2');
    var sidebar = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$3');

    return [offsets.split("\n"), rawVals, sidebar.split("\n")];
  }
```

Code as snippet:

```js
var input = `00054260: 8502 a861 2000 0000 3c40 8c49 fd5d 8646  ...a ....@.I.].F
00054270: 3c40 8c49 ac00 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000  &lt;@.I............
00054280: c003 000a b042 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  .....B..&gt;.......
00054290: 0000 0000 cf11 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  ................
000542a0: c100 6300 6f00 6c00 6f00 7200 7300 2e00  ..c.o.l.o.r.s...
000542b0: 6a00 7000 6700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  j.p.g...........
000542c0: 0502 f4e0 2000 0000 6040 8c49 7967 3e49  .... ...@.Iyg&gt;I
000542d0: 6040 8c49 4000 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000  @.I@...........`;

function getSplitXxdOutput(content){
  var splitRegex = /([a-fA-F0-9]*:)(?: )((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4} ){8})(?: )(.{16})/g
  var offsets = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$1');
  var rawVals = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$2');
  var sidebar = content.replace(new RegExp(splitRegex), '$3');

  return [offsets.split("\n"), rawVals, sidebar.split("\n")];
}

var output = getSplitXxdOutput(input);
console.log(output);
```

The content variable is a string that contains the `xxd` output. The global regular expression is written to splitRegex and splits the output in 3 capturing groups:

1. all a-F characters and numbers followed by a ":"
2. all a-F characters and numbers followed by a space and this 4 x 8 (xxxx times 8)
3. the values (can be any character, 16 of them)

Some ideas and what I have tried to solve the problem:

- I have checked the regular expression on regexr.com where it behaves as expected, even with the aforementioned output. Which makes me think the problem is not related to the regular expression.
- I have the feeling that the reason for the unexpected behaviour is caused by the "<" character. When it is removed manually, the problem seems to be solved.
- I have tried escaping some of the special characters but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Since I am not certain of the success of the used method, I didn't include it in the question.
- I could replace the character but then the output is altered with, which is not the solution I want.

Is there a way to write "<" without escaping it and to avoid it being executed or cause the issue?

Output of console.log that is retrieved from the

```
 element:
```

'''html
00054260: 8502 a861 2000 0000 3c40 8c49 fd5d 8646  ...a ....@.I.].F
00054270: 3c40 8c49 ac00 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000  <@.I............
00054280: c003 000a b042 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  .....B..>.......
00054290: 0000 0000 cf11 0000 8b95 0e00 0000 0000  ................
000542a0: c100 6300 6f00 6c00 6f00 7200 7300 2e00  ..c.o.l.o.r.s...
000542b0: 6a00 7000 6700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  j.p.g...........
000542c0: 0502 f4e0 2000 0000 6040 8c49 7967 3e49  .... ...`@.Iyg&gt;I 000542d0: 6040 8c49 4000 8484 8400 0000 0000 0000`  @.I@...........
'''

It is retrieved with:

`var selectedHtml = document.getElementById(id).querySelectorAll("code");
var content = selectedHtml[1].querySelectorAll(".xxd-content");`

Comment: I've added a snippet with your function and input example. Can you please modify it and add a "working" input that shows the actual problem (at least for me it works as expected).

Comment: I'm not sure how the rest of your logic plays out but I'm gonna assume you forgot to `rawVals.split("\n")`

Comment: I would personally go for `var matches = [...s.matchAll(/^(\d+): ([\da-f]{4}(?: [\da-f]{4}){7}) + (.+)$/gm)];`, loop the results, and access `match[1]`, `match[2]`, and `match[3]` accordingly.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus. Thank you for your suggestion but the rawVals is a long string on purpose to allow another multiline regex later into the code. As for the regular expression, it is indeed another approach but for some reason it doesn't work on longer outputs (stops after the 5th line). But to be honest I don't think the reason is related to the use of replace and the regular expression. Is there another reason why you would go for this approach?

Comment: @user1974014 Unless I see more of your code and how the output is actually generated then it is impossible to guess why your code is failing. The code that you have supplied works as far as I can tell in `console.log()`. So it doesn't seem to be a regex issue, time to move along. Also, I suggested the singular regex because it takes less resources than performing a replacement 3 times.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that makes sense, thanks for the advice. It's true that you won't be able to tell without the whole code.

Comment: @user1974014 `console.log()` the extracted content of `<pre></pre>`. Odds are that there is some extra whitespace that you are not accounting for.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have added the requested output to the question.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle that reproduces the error https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=30BbViSqVt. So far I found out that the issue is related to how the characters are encoded and decoded. The question now is how to resolve the issue without breaking the code. @MonkeyZeus I also plan on changing the regular expression to the one you have created once the issue is resolved.

Comment: The problem was caused by using innerHTML instead of innerText. Thanks for all the help. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Great, glad I could help you narrow it down.